# In R can I find the environment associated with a lazy argument?

Tags: r, closures, name-binding

Sorry this is a little complicated.

I want to capture an argument expression, but also know which environment it should be evaluated in. Something like this:

```
make.promise = function(x = print(b), b = 7) {
    expr = substitute(x)
    env  = parent.frame()

    function() {
        eval(expr, env)
    }
}

p1 = (
    function() {
        a = 2
        make.promise(print(a))
    }
)()

p2 = make.promise()
```

The problem is, if no argument is supplied for `x`, its environment becomes the local environment of `make.promise()`, and I don't know how to detect that. Is there a function other than `substitute` I could use that also captures the environment?

Comment: What are you trying to do? A little context would be helpful. Do you know about delayedAssign?

Comment: Actually, I solved my problem another way, now I'm just curious ;). And yes, I make extensive used of delayedAssign()...

Comment: care to share your alternative way of solving the problem as an Answer?

Comment: Yes... I removed the default argument, so the environment would always be parent.frame() (I think this should be true).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest implementation of `make.promise` would be:

```
make.promise <- function(x) {
    function() x
}
```

But I don't think that's what you're looking for. I'm not aware of any way to find the environment associated - you might try email the r-devel mailing list.

Comment: Yeah... what I really wanted to do was get something that could be *re*evaluated more than once... but as I said up above if I don't have a default it should always be parent.frame(). But it doesn't seem (after more searching) there is any pure-R way to get the environment of a promise, though it could easily be done in C.